# python sdk resource group

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I am using python for obtaining vnets, subnets, and all IP addresses which are in use (and tags for RG).

I would like to use get_client_from_cli_profile and login via az login.

I have a number of subscriptions but I am not able to list all RGs from each subscription.

```
    def test():
    subscription_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(SubscriptionClient)
    resource_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ResourceManagementClient)
    out = ''

    for g in subscription_client.subscriptions.list():
        for v in resource_client.resource_groups.list(subscription_id=g.subscription_id):
            out = out + '\n' + " " + g.subscription_id + " " + v.name

    return out

print(test())
```

This code shows the same RG for each subscription.
Do you know how I can list all subnets within vnet?
Do you know how I can list all IP addresses within each subnet? I would like to check which IP addresses are used.

Comment: Have you tried the documentation?

Comment: I have not found in documentation how I can list resource groups per subscription. Please check my code. When I log on to azure I can list subscriptions but resource group is taken from first subscription even if I changed sub-id. In doc I need to provide credentials but as long as I use cli I assume that this is not required.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: What is the reason that you do not accept the answer?! Also no response. If you still want to solve the problem, please give more questions. Or if it solves your problem, please accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, the Authentication you used is not an appropriate one. You can see the description of the CLI profile:

> Return a SDK client initialized with current CLI credentials, CLI
> default subscription and CLI default cloud.

**This code shows the same RG for each subscription**

As I know, there will be only one subscription set as the default. You can see that in the output when you log in. So you got the same groups even if you set different subscriptions. And take a look at the list function for the group:

```
Gets all the resource groups for a subscription.
```

It does not have the parameter as subscription_id. The parameter `filter` just used to filter the group in the same subscription.

You can change the code like this to loop the different subscriptions and get groups in different subscriptions:

```
import subprocess

def test():
  subscription_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(SubscriptionClient)
  out = ''

  for g in subscription_client.subscriptions.list():
    cmd = f"az account set --subscription {g.subscription_id}"
    result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = result.communicate()
    resource_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ResourceManagementClient)
      for v in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
          out = out + '\n' + " " + g.subscription_id + " " + v.name

  return out
```

**Do you know how I can list all subnets within vnet? Do you know how I can list all IP addresses within each subnet?**

To get the subnets of a VNet. You can use the [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_05_01.operations.subnetsoperations?view=azure-python#list-resource-group-name--virtual-network-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) function. This function will give you the address prefix of the subnet. It means what IP address you can use. There is no function to list all the IP addresses of the subnet one by one.